# Can not disable LazyLoading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I try to disable the LazyLoading but it doesn't work. Does someboy know what I'm doing wrong? I also defined the properties which are "virtual" as not virtual.
I followed this tutorial here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

```
 public partial class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DataContext1")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Payments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Category)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

I get the same error with or without the "virtual" keyword("Category" is every time NULL):

[image]

Comment: How do you know lazy loading wasn't disabled? What query did you execute, what happened? What did the generated SQL query look like? There may be an issue with the query that forces it to load objects one by one. That's not lazy loading though.

Comment: @Nikola Matovic Remove the `virtual` keyword from all your navigation properties. It will be disabled automatically.

Comment: Or you may be trying to return data from an ASP.NET controller that refers to related entities that *weren't* loaded as part of the query. In this case you'll get an error saying the context was disposed. That's not a lazy loading issue either, the query simply didn't ask for those entities

Comment: I removed now all "virtual" Keywords in my DataContext and in my Modelclasses, but it neverthless doesn't work.

Comment: @NikolaMatovic what doesn't work? Post the classes, the query you tried and the generated SQL. You're asking people to *guess* what's wrong, or try to guess what the code may be doing

Comment: I posted now a image, it should help now

Comment: @NikolaMatovic if you get a NULL it means there are no data to load, not that lazy loading was involved. If lazy loading still worked, you *would* get data when you tried accessing that property. Post your *code*, not images of the code.

Comment: @NikolaMatovic `dc.Payments.ToList()` *doesn't* ask for any categories. If lazy loading worked, the categories would be loaded when you asked for them. Since it's *disabled*, `Category` remains empty

Comment: No, If I load it explicit it is not null, so I have data but it doesn't load

Comment: @NikolaMatovic because you disabled lazy loading and never asked for the `Category` entities. That's what lazy loading does, it loads things you didn't ask from the start. It *doesn't* mean that every related entity will be loaded when you ask for a root entity

Comment: @NikolaMatovic you need to add `.Include(p=>p.Category)` to eagerly load the related `Category` entity

Comment: You say " it loads things you didn't ask from the start" so with dc.Payments.ToList(); I don't ask for any Category so if I disabled LazyLoading it should Load the Categories?

Comment: Or how can I load this Categories without asking? That's what I want.

Answer (score -1):

To turn off lazy loading for a particular property do not make it virtual and to turn off lazy loading for all entities in the context, just set its configuration property to false.

Considering that, seems that your code already turned off lazy loading for all entities of your context.